# BuildConfig.DEBUG expecting member declaratuon Error

Tags: android, kotlin, buildconfig

Why using `BuildConfig.DEBUG` inside `companion object` cause `expecting member declaratuon` Error?

code:

```
class API {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: Retrofit
        private const val baseUrl = baseURL

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC)
            builder.addInterceptor(interceptor)
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code around it?

Comment: You can't put code inside companion object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a call outside a function or constructor. You cannot have if-statements outside method bodies, which applies to both Kotlin and Java.

`object`s are classes too, all though they follow the singleton pattern. You still can't put if-statements outside method bodies. The class-level declarations can only contain methods, constructors, and fields, and some blocks (i.e. `init`), not if-statements and calls to the defined variables.

In addition, you're using Java syntax which won't compile at all. Use Kotlin syntax instead and move it to an init block inside the companion object.

The init block is called like initialization when the companion object is initialized.

```
companion object{
    //Other declarations

    init{
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            var interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
            builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);//I have no clue where you define builder, but I'm assuming you've done it *somewhere* and just left it out of the question
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use an if statement as a top level declaration like that, you have to declare it inside a function or init block.

So something like this, perhaps:

```
class API {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: Retrofit
        private const val baseUrl = baseURL

        init {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
                builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```